# How to overcome this error when running a script in crontab?

Tags: cron

This is basically my script.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
#set -x

PATH=/usr/jdk/instances/current/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/ss7/access/bin:/opt/ss7/sgc/bin:/opt/ss7/access/install:/opt/ss7/sgc/install:/usr/jdk/instances/current/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/openwin/bin:/usr/ucb:/opt/stg/5.0/bin:/opt/stg/5.0/tools

/opt/stg/5.0/bin/ctl status all > stgstatus.txt

MINUTE=`cat stgstatus.txt |grep traffic |awk '{print $2}' |cut -d"|" -f1`

if [ $MINUTE -eq 0 ];then
    /opt/stg/5.0/bin/ctl restart all
fi
```

However when crontab tried to run it, it will always have this error. I didn't have any `whoami` command in my script, why the error appeared?

```
From stg Sat May  2 19:49 MYT 2015
To: stg
Subject: Output from "cron" command
MIME-Version:
Content-Type:
Content-Length:

Your "cron" job on ckpgumb10
/var/tmp/checkstgstatus.sh

produced the following output:

/opt/stg/5.0/bin/ctl[906]: whoami:  not found
```

This is how my crontab looks like.

```
49 * * * * /var/tmp/checkstgstatus.sh
```

EDIT #1

The format of temporary file, stgstatus.txt looks like below.

```
# | Handler      | Mode         |    PID | Start Time | CPU time | Command
==============================================================================
 1 | stg_d7       | standard     |  14998 |     May_01 |    00:00 | /opt/stg/5.0/bin/daemon
Detailed stg_d7 status (stg_d7status):
0 - IWU running
release SunOS5.10 5.0.0.70
node ckpgumb10 172.19.144.181
started 2015.05.01 20:04:39
traffic 0|0|32768 (last minute|hour|day)
```

end of detailed status, stg_d7status returned 0 (all ok)

```
 2 | tcapproxy    | standard     |  15105 |     May_01 |    09:25 | java
   |              |              |  15102 |     May_01 |    00:04 | lsr-relay
Detailed tcapproxy status (tcapproxystatus):
05/02/15-19:30:05 TcapProxy is running.
end of detailed status, tcapproxystatus returned 0 (all ok)
```

Comment: Did you try adding `export PATH` after setting it?

Comment: Also, you have a problem with the temporary file `stgstatus.txt` which you create. First of all you don't clean it up. But more importantly, you don't know what the current working directory will be during execution by `cron` so you cannot guarantee that you can even create it properly in the first place. Here, the simplest solution is to avoid the temp file altogether since you don't need it: you can pipe the output of `/opt/stg/5.0/bin/ctl status all` directly into `grep`.

Comment: What @Celada said. You don't even need `grep`, actually. You could do the whole thing in a single `awk` call. [Edit] your question to include the format of `stgstatus.txt` and I'll give you the relevant command.

Comment: Hi Celada, I am relatively new to this. I will have to find out what export PATH does. Secondly, is it necessary to remove the stgstatus.txt after creating it? Since it will be automatically replaced every time the script is executed. Thirtly, do you mean i should state the directory in front of the temp file if i attempt to create it?

Comment: What is `/opt/stg/5.0/bin/ctl`?  The error message looks like it is saying that `/opt/stg/5.0/bin/ctl` is a script that is calling `whoami`.

Comment: Hi g man,  It is a command by application

Comment: Hi all, problem is solved after adding exporting path n stating the location of temporary files. Thanks a lor for your help.